# Powershell Compress-Archive include empty directories

Tags: powershell, compress-archive

I need to include empty directories along with files in a zip file. I can do this manually just fine with 7-Zip but I wanted to automate it because I do this quite a lot. I recently started learning powershell so I decided to give it a go.

My problem is that `Compress-Archive` automatically discards empty directories. My workaround is (`$Files` is a parameter to the script):

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path . | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $Files }
$placeholders = @()
foreach ($item in $items) {
    if (($item | Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0 ) {
        $placeholders += (New-Item -Path "$item\.placeholder")
    }
}
```

and at the end of the script

```
foreach ($item in $placeholders) {
    $item.Delete() 
}
```

which works but it is not pretty as it results in placeholder files being in the final zip.

Is there a good way to compress empty directories in powershell?

**EDIT** whole script with version info at the bottom:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    # Files and folders to compress, comma separated
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]
    $Files,

    # zip file to create
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]
    $ZipName
)

if (-not $ZipName.Contains(".zip")) {
    $ZipName += ".zip"
}

$items = Get-ChildItem -Path . | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $Files }
$placeholders = @()
foreach ($item in $items) {
    if (($item | Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0 ) {
        $placeholders += (New-Item -Path "$item\.placeholder")
    }
}

if ((Get-ChildItem -Path . | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ZipName } | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0) {
    Remove-Item -Path "$ZipName"
}

$items | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $ZipName

foreach ($item in $placeholders) {
    $item.Delete() 
}

# output of Get-Host
# Name             : ConsoleHost
# Version          : 5.1.19041.610
# InstanceId       : c799930e-ea5e-4ec9-9e5d-41d949bf4ee4
# UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
# CurrentCulture   : en-GB
# CurrentUICulture : en-GB
# PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
# DebuggerEnabled  : True
# IsRunspacePushed : False
# Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

**EDIT2** very weird stuff. Tested it again and I swear it does not work for me. If I give it the names of empty directories it doesn't even create a zip file. I'm going to reinstall Windows as soon as my new ssd arrives, maybe that fixes it.

By the way I needed this for Wordpress plugin development as you have to upload the plugins in a zip file. I uploaded the archive I created with this script and it produced a very weird result. Instead of correctly uncompressing the zip as Wordpress has done every single time before what it did was something like this:

```
some\file\which\should\be\in\a\directory.php
weird\file\again.php
normal.php
```

No, those are **not** paths, they are filenames. On Windows I can uncompress it just fine. I am so confused.

Comment: I cannot duplicate. Empty directories are included in the zip file. What version of PS are you using? Probably best to show your Compress-Archive command.

Comment: @DougMaurer I edited the question so the whole script and version info is there

Comment: By saying `| Where-Object { $_.Name -in $Files }` you're automatically filtering those folders without a "File" hence those empty folders are not being compressed. Unless, $Files actually contains Names of Folders you're looking for.

Comment: @santisq it does contain the names of the directories, see parameter description

Comment: Confirming that I have the same problem. Zipping empty folders in Powershell results in no file, and frustratingly no error returned. In my case, it means I need to check for existence of files before attempting to zip, otherwise subsequent actions with the zip file I thought I created will fail.

Answer (score 1):

[Be warned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.3#description):

> The Compress-Archive cmdlet ignores hidden files and folders when creating or updating the archive file.

If your directory **only contains hidden files** it may **appear to be empty** ([if you haven't told File Explorer to show hidden files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5)). Then when you use `Compress-Archive` it will **actually be empty** due to that behavior.

The docs go on to say:

> To ensure hidden files and folders are compressed into the archive, use the .NET API instead.

---

This appears to be [fixed in 2.0.0](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/66), but at time of writing that's been [stuck as a preview release](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/releases/tag/v2.0.1-preview1) since Aug 2022.